# How to dynamically allocate an array of pointers in C++?

Tags: c++

I have the following class

```
class Node
{
    int key;
    Node**Nptr;
public:
    Node(int maxsize,int k);
};
Node::Node(int maxsize,int k)
{
   //here i want to dynamically allocate the array of pointers of maxsize
   key=k;
}
```

Please tell me how I can dynamically allocate an array of pointers in the constructor -- the size of this array would be maxsize.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Node::Node(int maxsize,int k)
{
   NPtr = new Node*[maxsize];
}
```

But as usual, you are probably better off using a std::vector of pointers.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you want to create matrix of 3 rows and 4 cols then,

```
int **arr = new int * [3];  //first allocate array of row pointers

for(int i=0 ; i<rows ; ++i)
{
   arr[i] = new int[4]; // allocate memory for columns in each row
}
```

Comment: Why is the * added after the int rather than before in the first line?

Answer (score 2):

That will be `Nptr = new Node*[maxsize];` Also, remember to use `delete[]` in destructor.